# Object content changing without implicit setter method used

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to understand which concept is behind the following variable $service evolving without seeming to be changed by the developer at anypoint in the code.

I noticed that before the line:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

the variable `$service` is an empty Service class object but after that, it contains new data if a form was passed in the request.

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="app_service_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request, ServiceRepository $serviceRepository): Response
{
    $service = new Service();
    $form = $this->createForm(ServiceType::class, $service);
    var_dump($service);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    var_dump($service);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $serviceRepository->add($service, true);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_service_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('service/new.html.twig', [
        'service' => $service,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

What is the behind the scenes that changes the $service variable after the handleRequest implicitly? It seems that there is some form of binding going on. How can I learn to write such code myself? Is there a name for this programming pattern?

Comment: Symfony is mapping POST vars into the form data element (`$service`) when the `handleRequest` method is executed. Dig into that method if you wish to know more. see https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms

Comment: You might be asking about the property accessor which is also documented. Suppose you Service entity has a property called 'name'. You mapped 'name' in your ServiceType class resulting in a form element with a name of 'name'. When data is posted  the handler looks to see if $service has a public property called 'name'. If so it sets it. If not it looks for a public method called setName and uses it if found. I think it also looks for isName. Maybe a few others. Basically just a trick to avoid the need to explicitly define setters in your form types.

Comment: "How can I learn to write such code myself?" - do you **need** to write such code on your own? Using Symfony components is a good way to not write such complicated stuff on your own, as there might be a lot of cases to consider. Also, all that code is freely available, and using any debugger, you can even step through the execution of that component to watch how it works